# How to build android service to use in Delphi application

Tags: delphi, service, jar

I need to do some image processing in Delphi 10.2 android service, but that is not possible due to the fact that unit FMX.Types is included by TBitmap unit.

So I decided to write a simple android service in Java to delegate image processing to it.

How can I create a jar file with Java service attachable by Delphi?

Comment: You might be able do the image processing using the native Java Bitmap class. What exactly does it need to do?

Comment: This http://dannywind.nl/auto-start-delphi-xe5-android-app-after-boot/ might give you some pointers even though it is quite out of date now.

Comment: I need to scale and paint on them. Delphi services have many limitations, so I don't want to stick with another one while working with native bitmap there.

Comment: I've already done not broadcast receiver as in Danny Wind article, but I don't know how to compile and as service from Android studio, I'm new to it.